# Bash: assignment of variable on same line not altering echo behavior

Tags: bash

```
a=2
a=3 echo $a     #prints 2
```

can someone explain why would anyone use the above code in line-2.
 a=3 will be ignored as there is no "enter" after it.
But I saw it in script like above and not sure about the purpose.

Comment: `$a` is expanded before `a=3` is evaluated. Usually, `var=val command` is used to set an environment variable to be seen by `command` during its execution, but nowhere else. In this case `$a` will be `3` ‘within’ `echo`, but its argument is still `2`.

Comment: It's probably because someone wanted to test your conclusion.

Comment: @Biffen - Spot on.  You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Biffen thx for explaining.

Comment: Even if it *did* work, I can't imagine a situation where you would want `a=$value echo $a` over `echo $value`.

Comment: The purpose, in the script you saw, was to set the variable **in the environment** for the duration of the command being run -- implying that that command, unlike `echo`, inspects and modifies its behavior based on environment variables.

Comment: @chepner -- it would be useful if `a` were a long string and one wanted to use it multiple times in the rest of the command line. For instance I came here because I want to do a `find . -type d` and egrep directories out of the output. They may appear /between/ slashes or at the end$ of a & I want to trim both with egrep. My regex-fu isn't strong enough to come up with a way to do both in the same egrep, but I can chain multiple egreps and get the effect I want. Since there are several directories I want to trim, my `a` would look something like this: a="foo|bar|baz" find . -type d | egrep ...

Comment: @JohnnyLambada That's what *any* variable is for. You don't need special syntax to allow it. Pre-command assignments are for something different; altering the *environment* in which a command executes, not the command line to *produce* the command to execute.

Answer (score 14):

`$a` is expanded by the shell (Bash) before `a=3` is evaluated. So `echo` sees its argument as `2`, which is what it prints. (If you `set -x` you can see that what gets executed is `a=3 echo 2`.)

`var=val command` is used to set an environment variable to be seen by `command` *during its execution*, but nowhere else. So when `command` reads environment variables (e.g. using [`getenv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv)), to it `$var` is `val`.

If `echo` were to look up `$a` while running, it would have the value `3`.

Answer (score 7):

The parent process expands `a` *before* the environment is setup in which it sets a different value (3) for `a`. Despite the fact that variable `a` set to `3` by the `echo` executes, the value was expanded already. So it's too late.

You can instead do:

```
a=3 bash -c 'echo $a'
```